# AdMob ads in MainActivity or in each Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, ads

I'm making an Android app that uses a `Main Activity` and each screen is a separate `Fragment` inside the same activity.

I want to place an AdMob Ad at the bottom of each screen. What is the best approach to this?

1) Add only one Ad inside the `activity`, below the space that `fragments` will take

2) Add the Ad inside each and every `fragment`.

Right now I've implemented the 2nd method, but I'm having trouble with the padding of the activity when I'm trying to display `SMART_BANNERS`dues to the `activity's` padding (left and right)

Which is the best and correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st approach is better because the ad does not need to load every time the fragments are switched.
With the 2nd approach the user might not see the ad at all if he switches between fragments too fast and too often.

Comment: That is a valid point. I went with the 1st approach and everything seems ok

Answer (score 1):

Have as few ad views as possible. The best way would be to have one in the Activity since AdMob will refresh the ad necessarely and you dont have to worry about loading times which can be a problem if you change fragments a lot.

Also mind that AdMob seems to have problems with Activity context causing memory leaks (well the version I used at least). So make sure you use application context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the answer. I went that way, with only 1 AdView and everything runs smoothly (for now)

Answer (score 0):

I had used Admob and if you have plenty requests from 1 ID your app could fail. This is because there is a maximum number permitted in android for ads.

I would use it in your main so you can display any fragment with only one ad.